# What is python3mu?

Tags: python, python3

I'm setting up PyDev for Eclipse, and I have to choose a version of Python for the interpretor.  I want to use Python3, and I've been using `python3` as my interpretor, so I thought `/usr/bin/python3` would have been the obvious choice.  However, another option there is `python3mu`.  I ran this in the terminal and it seemed to function exactly like `python3`.  My questions are: Which one is the correct one to use as the interpretor for Eclipse? and What is the difference between the two?

EDIT:  Just wanted to let you guys know that my google-fu was not good enough to find out what python3mu was.

Comment: Check this out [link](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/ubuntu-main-i386/python3-minimal_3.2.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb.html)

Comment: @tomasz74 Ahh, so this is a version without many of the modules added on by default?  And so I should use the regular one right?  Also, just put that link in an answer, and I'll give you the green check mark.

Comment: No, 'mu' has nothing to do with minimal

Comment: Related question on Stack Overflow: [Difference between python3 and python3m executables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16675865/4518341).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In python 3, some compile options (the abi flags) are reflected in the binary name and the name of cached bytecode in `__pycache__` directories. mu means`--with-pymalloc` and `--with-wide-unicode`

See also http://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys#sys.abiflags and http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/

Comment: I've looked at the links, and it appears that these only apply to libraries and such.  Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think that that applies to the version of Python you're running.  Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: ABI means "Application Binary Interface". This includes signatures of all functions and constants as used in a program and is a sort of contract between libraries and applications. e.g. in `--with-pymalloc` builds, memory allocation works differently. If libraries don't know this about the binary, they'll try to do things that make python crash :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface

Comment: As a programmer who does not work much with python (read and write files only), do I need the python3..m or can I remove it?